# How do I make the standard scrollbar of a panel disappear?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

On my form, I have a panel with a varying number of buttons. They are all placed in a row and are all set to dock top. Since I dislike the design of the included scrollbars and the lack of possibility to change the color, I created my own scrollbar, which works great. The problem is that in order for it to work, AutoScroll must be set to true. Now, when the summed height of the content exceeds the height of the panel, the standard scrollbar automatically appears and I can not get rid of it.

So here is my question. How can I make the scrollbar disappear?

What I have tried:

I tried every combination.

First example:

```
this.panel_Playlists.AutoScroll = false;
this.panel_Playlists.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
this.panel_Playlists.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
this.panel_Playlists.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
this.panel_Playlists.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
this.panel_Playlists.AutoScroll = true;
```

Second example:

```
public enum ScrollBarDirection
{
    SB_HORZ = 0,
    SB_VERT = 1,
    SB_CTL = 2,
    SB_BOTH = 3
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    ShowScrollBar(panel_Playlists.Handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_BOTH, false);
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

No matter what I try, nothing works. Either the scrollbar flickers or it is permanently visible.

Request for quick help.

LG

Comment: Can you overlay your sbar over the system's?

Comment: No. My bar is set to dock right and the panel is set to fill to ensure a dynamic size control.

Comment: You could still try. set its left = parent.width - bar.width etc..

Comment: I solved it by using nested panels which is quite awkward.